# Run and debug DBeaver with NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, dbeaver

Context: I am using [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) to access and view MariaDB databases. Now I have an issue with accessing a remote database via SSH tunnel. I cannot connect although it should.

I want to run and debug DBeaver in NetBeans. But as I have very few experience with Java and none with Maven I am not sure how to do that.

I have cloned the Git repository of [DBeaver](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver) and opened in NetBeans. Now I see this project structure:

[image]

How can I run the application in debug mode?

**Update**:
I have already right clicked on the project and selected "Clean and Build", which ended with "Build Success". But the menu entry "Run" in the context menu of the project is still disabled.

Comment: Nothing in DBeaver logs ? https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Log-files

Comment: @PeterMmm There is a log but it is not relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since DBeaver is an Eclipse RCP application, you need to use Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP developers. See https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Develop-in-Eclipse.

You can also use IntelliJ IDEA (https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Develop-in-IDEA), but that requires building DBeaver in Eclipse first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That helps a lot - especially the link to the DBeaver wiki. I haven't found that during my search :-(